# How can I group the rows of a table (by the "Quantity" cell)?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables, tabulator

I think this is a common problem, but I don't know of any obvious solution.

I have a table of items to order (i.e. a sales list). One of the columns in this table is "quantity". Is there a tool (library, or something) that would automatically group records (rows) by itself, and increase the cell "quantity"?

In short, I want the table to convert this (Row ID, Name, Price):

```
3, Red ball, 3 pieces, $ 5
3, Red ball, 3 pieces, $ 5
3, Red ball, 3 pieces, $ 5
```

into this (name, QUANTITY, price) :

```
Red ball, 3 pieces, $ 5
```

The details of the problem are below ...
Why do I need this?
I store each position (row) of the table on the server. But because of the "quantity" column, I have to create new records in the new model, in which I create duplicate records for each item.
For example, the string (name, quantity, price):

```
Red ball, 3 pieces, $ 5
```

Duplicated to another model as (row id, name, price):

```
3, Red ball, 3 pieces, $ 5
3, Red ball, 3 pieces, $ 5
3, Red ball, 3 pieces, $ 5
```

This is done in order to be able to work with these records (for example, count their number, link to other records, etc.). But everything spoils the "Quantity" column, if it were not there, then I would not have to duplicate anything in different models of my application, I would just display the same records, and already "SOME ADDON/LIB/PLUGIN/SNIPPET WHICH I ASK YOU ABOUT" would display a table and automatically grouped identical rows into one, counting their number in the "Quantity" column on the client side (JS). Forgive me for description my problem, I think the first part of the question will be enough ...

I am currently using the TABULATOR (JS) tables, a very cool tool, but I have not found such a built-in function in it ...

Data format from server:

```
 var tabledata = [
    
    {
        order_item_id:6,
        name:'red ball',
        price:5,
        
     },

    {
        order_item_id:7,
        name:'red ball',
        price:5,
        
     },

    {
        order_item_id:8,
        name:'red ball',
        price:5,
        
     },

     ]
```

Comment: From where do your data come from and in which format? It seems a problem that you could solve with a simple array `reduce()` (if you search for "removing duplicates from an array" you will find a lot of solutions) or even with an SQL query (if data are stored in a relational database) but you should add a bit more info.

Comment: I'll try to be even shorter and clearer:
I get a lot of lines from the server (some of them are repeated 3-4 times).
I want to create a table based on this data, but the repeated rows should appear as one row, and their number should be displayed in the "quantity" column.

Comment: That's clear but if you do not show how those lines look like when they are sent by the server (that is to say, the server response), people won't be able to tell you how you can manipulate them in order to achieve your goal. Or, if you prefer to receive those data from the server, which is possible too, you should provide some more info about the database. The issue is not your request was not clear, the issue is you did not provide enough information to answer it.

Comment: var tabledata = [
    
  {
      order_item_id:6,
      name:'red ball',
      price:5,
      
   },

  {
      order_item_id:7,
      name:'red ball',
      price:5,
      
   },

  {
      order_item_id:8,
      name:'red ball',
      price:5,
      
   },

   ]

Comment: Is it correct the same item (e.g. "red ball") has different `order_item_id`s (e.g. 6, 7 and 8)? Anyway, as I mentioned, you can achieve your goal by using the `reduce()` and the `findIndex()` array methods: you use`reduce((acc, item) => { /* ...function body */ }, [])` to loop through your results, check if the accumulator already contains an item with the same name (with `findIndex(item => { /* ...function body */ })`) and either update the product `quantity` property or add the the new product accordingly; have you tried? Please share your attempted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const tabledata = [{
  order_item_id: 5,
  name: 'blue ball',
  price: 3,
}, {
  order_item_id: 6,
  name: 'red ball',
  price: 5,
}, {
  order_item_id: 7,
  name: 'red ball',
  price: 5,
}, {
  order_item_id: 8,
  name: 'red ball',
  price: 5,
}, {
  order_item_id: 9,
  name: 'blue ball',
  price: 3,
}, {
  order_item_id: 10,
  name: 'blue ball',
  price: 3,
}, {
  order_item_id: 11,
  name: 'red ball',
  price: 5,
}, {
  order_item_id: 12,
  name: 'yellow ball',
  price: 15,
}]

const grouped = tabledata.reduce((acc, item) => {
  /*
   * check whether the accumulator already contains a product with the same name
   * (if it does, return its index otherwise return -1)
   */
  const index = acc.findIndex(_item => _item.name === item.name);

  if (index > -1) {
    /*
     * if the product is already present, increase its quantity by 1
     */
    acc[index].quantity = acc[index].quantity + 1;
  } else {
    /*
     * if the product is not present, add it to the accumulator array
     */
    acc.push({
      name: item.name,
      unit_price: item.price,
      quantity: 1
    });
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log('### TABLEDATA:\n', tabledata);
console.log('### GROUPED:\n', grouped);
```